# k6 postman - Request tags not added to postman test

Tags: postman, load-testing, k6

In my postman-to-k6 converted k6 script, I have a request level tag which I use for the api request name.

```
postman[Request]({
  name: "Create Account",
  id: "ce390940-d07a-485a-8796-298708c4a720",
  method: "POST",
  address: "REDACTED",
  data: '{
    REDACTED
  }',
  headers: {
    REDACTED
  },
  tags: {
    requestUrl: "Create Account"
  },
  post(response) {        
    tests["status was 2XX"] = response.status.toString().split('')[0] == "2";
    tests["status was 404"] = response.status === 404;
    tests["status was 5XX"] = response.status.toString().split('')[0] == "5";
  }
});
```

I send my data to an InfluxDB, where a Grafana VM retrieves the data to add to a dashboard.

When viewing a graph I call "Checks per Second", I can see all checks globally with this query:

```
SELECT sum("value") FROM "checks" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval), "check" fill(null)
```

However, I want to be able to view the checks-per-request, which would make use of my request level tag.

I do this with the following query:

```
SELECT sum("value") FROM "checks" WHERE ("requestUrl" =~ /^$URL$/) AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval), "check" fill(null)
```

However, no data is returned from this result.

My conclusion is that k6 is not adding the tag to the postman test.

---

I know that base-k6 can do this with: https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6/check-val-sets-tags/

However, I don't believe the postman-k6 has this functionality, as I can't find any reference to it anywhere.

Does anyone know of a workaround, or a way to force the tag to show on the postman test?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see the `post` request here is just a js function that has access to the response, when it gets called after the request is made.

Given that there is nothing stopping you from just directly using the built-in check as usual and doing something along the lines of

```
  check(null, {
    "status was 2XX": response.status.toString().split('')[0] == "2",
    "status was 404": response.status === 404,
    "status was 5XX": response.status.toString().split('')[0] == "5",
  }, {"requestUrl": "Create Account"});
```

instead of the current `tests` definition you are having.

I would argue that you should just *not* have these checks, but instead use the fairly new [expectedStatuses](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-http/expectedstatuses-statuses/) call which will set a tag on the `http_req*` metrics of whether the expected status was seen.

You can additionally just make queries in grafana to check if the statuses were mostly 5xx or 400 or w/e else you need without having multiple checks which will push even more metrics.

Comment: I implemented your suggested changes, they work great! Thank you.

One graph I can't reproduce is a sum of all status codes.
I.e. There were 1000 200s, 50 404s, 0 500s etc..

The query I have so far is this:
`SELECT sum("value") FROM "http_reqs" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY "status"`